# Is there a way to get the usernames of the viewers of my live broadcast?

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I wanted to ask if there is any way to get the usernames of the viewers of my live broadcast while i am broadcasting...is this possible somehow through google API for youtube livestreaming?

Any help appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Would be a huge privacy violation if it was possible.

Comment: I understand i just thought it because not everyone is shown on my livestream until they chat.

Comment: @CBroe and that is why twitch is winning by a lot the "streaming" battle against youtube